Sequelize transactions are not working as expected
In this scenario, SQL transactions are utilized to insert data into three tables: Customer, Order, and OrderItems. The expected behavior is that if any of the queries within the transaction fail, the entire transaction should be rolled back, ensuring data consistency. However, it appears that the transactions are not functioning as intended, as they do not rollback when subsequent queries encounter errors and fail to insert data into the tables.
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { Order }  from "../models/order.model";
import IResponse from "../interfaces/response.interface";
import { CustomerModel  } from '../models/customer.model';
import db from '../database';
import { OrderItems } from '../models/orderitem.models';
import ProductModel from '../models/product.model';

class OrderController {
async createOrder(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
    interface Product {
        product_id: number;
        name: string;
        quantity: number;
        price: number;
    }

    try {
        const { products, name, email, phone, address } = req.body;
        let totalPrice = 0;
          // Calculate total price
          products.forEach((product: Product) => {
            const subtotal = product.quantity * product.price;
            totalPrice += subtotal;
        });
        const result = await db.transaction(async (t) => {
            // Create customer
            const customer = await CustomerModel.create({
                name: name,
                email: email,
                phone: phone,
                address: address,
                transaction: t // Assign transaction
            });
            const cust_id = customer.customer_id;

            // Create order
            const order = await Order.create({
                customer_id: cust_id,
                total_amount: totalPrice,
                order_date: new Date(),
                created_by: '1',
                transaction: t // Assign transaction
            });
            const order_id = order.order_id;

            // Create order items
            const orderItemsPromises: Promise<void>[] = products.map((product: Product) => {
                return OrderItems.create({
                    order_id: order_id,
                    product_id: product.product_id,
                    order_date: new Date(),
                    quantity: product.quantity,
                    price: product.price,
                    transaction: t // Assign transaction
                });
            });

            // Wait for all order items to be created
            await Promise.all(orderItemsPromises);

            return order; // Return the order created within the transaction
        });
        res.status(201).json({ message: 'Order created successfully' });
    } catch (error: any) {
        // Send error response
        console.error(error);
        const response: IResponse = {
            statusCode: 500,
            status: 'error',
            message: error.message,
            data: '',
        };
        res.status(500).json(response);
    }
}
}

In the sqquelize documentation and tried managed transaction , put all queries involved in the transaction are encapsulated within the transaction block. This ensures that if any query fails, the entire transaction is rolled back. But its not working as expected ?
